# PTIJ: Bearded vultures

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The "bearded vulture" is not allowed at the dinner table. [Lev. 11:13]  Would he be allowed if he shaved first?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would depend if he used a razor or not. If he used a razor it would be a siman that he was not keeping the mitzvos of the torah and would therefore remain forbidden at the table.

Answer (score 2):

The bearded vulture is not supposed to shave at all. There is a reason as to why you shouldn't eat it, but merely look at it if it were on your dinner table. And, you must glorify it as it says:

והדרת פני זקן

You shall glorify the face of a beard.